# как по кнопке запустить фрагмент

Tags: android, kotlin

я может чего то не понимаю(возможно так невозможно), есть фрагменти и как его запустить при нажатии кнопки из другово фрагмента

Comment: В целом - запустив транзацию, созданную через FragmentManager. Остальное - детали, в т.ч. то через какой FragmentManager и в какой контейнер вы хотите новый фрагмент поместить.

Answer (score 0):

Фрагмент не запускается а заменяется в контейнере, я использую для этого в extension классе две функции:

Для вызова из активити:

```
fun AppCompatActivity.replaceFragment(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, fragment: Fragment) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView, fragment)
        .commit()
}
```

Для вызова из фрагмента:

```
fun Fragment.replaceFragment(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, fragment: Fragment) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView, fragment)
        .commit()
}
```

Вызов из активити:

```
replaceFragment(supportFragmentManager,ordersListFragment.getInstance())
```

Вызов из фрагмента:

```
replaceFragment(parentFragmentManager,ordersListFragment.getInstance())
```

Comment: фрагмент находиться в навхост фрагмент как именно запустить из него